# Need help solving "ZeroDivisionError: division by zero"

Tags: python

I´m creating a program where I´m converting from one to two different money currencies. I´m getting an error that says `ZeroDivisionError: division by zero` but it also says, `local variable 'amount_nok' might be referenced before assignment`.

I've tried multiple solutions like creating new variables, or tried to remove any referenced variables that is not yet actually assigned, etc.

```
def getRate(FromValue, ToValue):
    if FromValue == 'NOK' and ToValue == 'USD':
        rate = 9.0169
    else:
        rate = 0
    return rate


def calculate():
    print('Convert an amount from NOK to EUR/USD')

    validValue = 'N'
    while validValue == 'N':
        validValue = 'Y'
        try:
            amount_nok = int(input("Enter amount you want to convert: "))
        except ValueError:
            validValue = 'N'
            print('Stop this stupidity! Pick a whole number!')

    rate_Nok_Eur = getRate('NOK', 'EUR')
    print('Amount EUR & USD bought for ' ,'%.2f' % (amount_nok) + ' NOK is '+ '%.2f' % (amount_nok / rate_Nok_Eur) + "\N{euro sign}"
          'og ', '%.2f' % (amount_nok/9.0169)+"\N{dollar sign}")

calculate()
```

I´m expecting the program to run the calculation without any errors during the startup phase of the program, so the final output would look something like this

```
Amount EUR & USD bought for 20 NOK is (dollar amount) and (euro amount)
```

Comment: Look very carefully at `toValue`

Comment: You're passing `'NOK'` and `'EUR'` to `getRate()`, which means it will return `0`, and the next line will divide by it.

Comment: Also, why define NOK/USD in getRate(), when you later use 9.0169 hard coded to calculate the USDs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your getRate method returns zero when you define `rate_Nok_Eur = getRate('NOK', 'EUR')`, so `amount_nok / rate_Nok_Eur` will gave you the error,

you need to specify the case when you have `getRate('NOK', 'EUR')`